# Search for Alarm with name in Cloudwatch

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to search for an alarm or to check if alarm already exists in CloudWatch using Java api?

I am currently doing this way but it doesnt look promising to me.

```
    long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    Dimension instanceDimension = new Dimension();
    instanceDimension.setName("InstanceId");
        instanceDimension.setValue("i-201cb891");

    //Check is Alarms with name exist.
    GetMetricStatisticsRequest getMetricStatisticsRequest  = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - offsetInMilliseconds))
            .withNamespace("AWS/EC2")
            .withPeriod(60 * 60)
            .withMetricName("StatusCheckFailed")
            .withStatistics("Average")
            .withDimensions(Arrays.asList(instanceDimension))
            .withEndTime(new Date());

    GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(getMetricStatisticsRequest);
    System.out.println("" + getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints().size());
    if(getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints().size() == 0) {
        PutMetricAlarmRequest request = new PutMetricAlarmRequest()
                .withActionsEnabled(true).withAlarmName("i-201cb891")
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold)
                .withDimensions(Arrays.asList(instanceDimension))
               // .withAlarmActions(getTopicARN())
                .withEvaluationPeriods(1)
                .withPeriod(60)
                .withThreshold(60.0D)
                .withStatistic(Statistic.Average)
                .withMetricName("StatusCheckFailed")
                .withNamespace("AWS/EC2");
        cloudWatch.putMetricAlarm(request);
        System.out.println("Alarm created for Instance with ID :  " + "i-201cb891");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Alarm exists with name : " + "i-201cb891");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AmazonCloudWatch interface to query for your alarms.

From AmazonCloudWatch API:

```
DescribeAlarmsResult describeAlarms(DescribeAlarmsRequest describeAlarmsRequest)
```

You can use this method to query for your alarms by name or by prefix, for instance.

The following code snippet shows how to use the API:

```
...

AmazonCloudWatch client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

DescribeAlarmsRequest request = new DescribeAlarmsRequest();

List<String> alarmNames = new ArrayList<String>();
alarmNames.add("alarmName1");
alarmNames.add("alarmName2");

request.setAlarmNames(alarmNames);

DescribeAlarmsResult result = client.describeAlarms(request);

List<MetricAlarm> alarms = result.getMetricAlarms();

for (MetricAlarm alarm : alarms) {
    System.out.println(alarm.getAlarmName());
}

...
```

[AWS SDK for Java API Reference - 1.10.43](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: how do i get the next set of alarms using token ? .. I think in first go it only gives me first 50 from the list